# How to dynamically position camera above centre of board game - Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile

I am writing a mobile game that dynamically generates 3d items on a canvas.

However, I am struggling with 2 things:

1. Have the underlying plane scale to fit the size of the screen
2. Shift the camera so that it moves directly above the plane and **looks down** at the objects.

Therefore, changing the scene from something like this:
[image]

To something like this:

[image: desired layout]

I have been going through the camera tutorials, but they mostly are for '3d games' and not for a camera that looks down from above, flattening the 3d space. I need to use 3d cubes because the game rotates them during play.

Would appreciate some tips on what material to look at!

Comment: Sooo...you know where the middle cube is, right? Why not position the camera at `[position of middle cube] + Vector3.Up * [arbitrary distance]`?

Comment: @Draco18s Thanks for this! This will actually work to position the camera.  For the plane, how can it be sized to fit the screen of the mobile device? Is it a calculation based on field of view of camera?

Comment: I have found the answer to scaling the canvas using Screen.width and Screen.height - now I just have to figure how to centre it.

Comment: You could just set the skybox color.

Comment: `gradlew setupDecompWorkspace and gradlew eclipse` is what I was looking for. Not sure what happened, then.